# Dúvida Consulta

Tags: sql, query, odbc

Não sei se alguém pode me ajudar, estou com um problema qual não sei como resolver. Sou novo em análise de dados e estou com uma demanda onde precisamos verificar o preço da ultima compra dos itens.

Realizei essa consulta:

```
    SELECT descricaoItem,
       custoEntrada,
       dataEntrada
FROM Est.NotaFiscalEntradaItens
ORDER BY dataEntrada DESC
```

Obtive esse resultado:

```
descricaoItem: CABO FLEXIVEL 2M
custoEntrada: 150
dataEntrada: 2023-09-26

descricaoItem: CABO FLEXIVEL 3M
custoEntrada: 200
dataEntrada: 2023-09-17

descricaoItem: CABO FLEXIVEL 5M
custoEntrada: 350
dataEntrada: 2023-09-15
```

Porém preciso que nesse select também adcione uma nova coluna, nessa coluna o código precisa trazer o custo de cada produto com a data anterior ou seja sempre trazer esse custo e na nova coluna o custo anterior mais proximo.
Exemplo: Se comprei um cabo flexivel no dia 25 e no dia 10 do mês 09, gostaria que nessa nova coluna do Select ele trouxesse o custo desse produto no dia mais próximo (penultimo) ou seja referente ao dia 25.
E assim sucessivamente com todos os itens.

Porém infelizmente como sou novo não sei como posso realizar esse select.

Desculpe se faltou alguma informação e obrigado à todos.

Comment: Você tentou fazer alguma consulta,  por exemplo usando a expressão SQL `CASE`, ou não fez nenhuma tentativa?

Comment: Não duplique perguntas. Os comentários foram bloqueados para que continuem na [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/587284/3635).